# Вводное ли это слово (словосочетание, оборот)? Почему запятые не просятся на бумагу?

Tags: вводные-слова, невыделение-вводных

> Предложенное Вами "разноголосый" не лечит моего страданья - многоголосья, в обоих случаях
> корень "голос", я же хотела бы избавиться от возможно кажущейся
> тавтологии - "многоголосый, каждый из  голосов которого..."
>
> (Не уверена в своих запятых! Но выделить ***возможно***
> или ***возможно кажущейся*** почему-то рука не поднимается!

(Из частной переписки.)

Comment: хор на много голосов, каждый из которых... (?)

Comment: Саша! Этот вопрос о другом! )))

Comment: Думаю, запятая нужна - слово "возможно" не приживается в качестве степени "кажимости", в отличие от следующего ряда с пристройками: мнимо кажущаяся, явно кажущаяся, предположительно кажущаяся тавтология (эти сочетания могут выступать в  качестве группы подлежащего). Даже если поставить в скобки "возможно() кажущуюся", разделяющая их запятая станет очевидной: (возможно, кажущуюся) - здесь сомнение в истинности утверждения о тавтологии, и потому "возможно" - вводное слово.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**...от возможно кажущейся тавтологии.**

Думаю, что "возможно" здесь является наречием, относится к причастию.

Можно сравнить два варианта с разными значениями (наречие и вводное слово): (1) Возможно надуманный довод оказался решающим. (2) Возможно, надуманный довод оказался решающим.

Таким образом, мы видим, что ***возможно*** может быть наречием

Примеры: Понятно стремление центра освободиться от возможно большего объема финансовых обязательств. [Николай Петров. Пограничный конфликт (2003) // «Еженедельный журнал», 2003.04.29]

Лишь чуть холодело внутри, в желудке, от возможно предстоящего мне унижения. [Владимир Маканин. Андеграунд, или герой нашего времени (1996-1997)] [